# R Shiny: allow line break within a row of renderTable

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following simple Shiny app below (silly example) which only displays a table produced by renderTable:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Issue"),
   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    ),
   mainPanel(
    tableOutput("example")
  )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 output$example <- renderTable({
  data.frame(
   "a" = 1,
   "b" = paste("hello","there",sep = "\n"),
   "c" = 3
  )
 },bordered = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The resulting table looks like the following:

[image: Table Output]

I want there to be a new line between "hello" and "there" in the rendered table. In other words, I want "there" to be on a new line but still within the same cell as "hello". Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Kind regards,
ACE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `sanitize.text.function` parameter (passed to `print.xtable`) and use HTML:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$example <- renderTable({
    data.frame(
      "a" = 1,
      "b" = paste("hello","there",sep = "<br>"),
      "c" = 3
    )
  },bordered = TRUE, sanitize.text.function=identity)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You little angel, you. :)